# list view items not getting filtered while typing in edittext.

Tags: android

I am using simple cursor adapter to filter list view items according to text typed in edit text. I couldn't do it. No error in code. But process i.e filtering doesn't occur. Listview stands still without any change. Can anyone help me?

This is my code.
>

`SimpleCursorAdapter sca;

ListView lv;

EditText searchtext;

lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

searchtext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eT_sth);`

```
searchtext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            sca.getFilter().filter(arg0);
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });

    sca.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {

        @Override
        public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence cse) {
            String pi=null;
            if(cse!=null)
                pi=cse.toString();
            return db.filteredItem(pi);
        }
    });

public Cursor filteredItem(String st) throws SQLException {
    Cursor mcursor = null;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    try {
        if (st == null || st.length() == 0) {
            String query = "SELECT * FROM" + this.TABLE_MIC2 + "";
            mcursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        } else {
            mcursor = db.query(this.TABLE_MIC2, new String[] { this.KEY_ID,
                    this.KEY_ITEMNUMBER, this.KEY_DESCRIPTION,
                    this.KEY_PICKINGSEQUENCE, this.KEY_QTYONHAND,
                    this.KEY_QTYCOUNTED, this.KEY_STOCKUNIT,
                    this.KEY_STATUS }, this.KEY_ITEMNUMBER + " like '%"
                    + st + "%'", null, null, null, null);
        }
        if (mcursor != null) {
            mcursor.moveToFirst();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return mcursor;

}
```

This is my listview method.

```
public void inserttolist(String SpnLocation) {
    try {
         cu = db.getdata(SpnLocation);
        String[] columns = new String[] { DatabaseHandler.KEY_ITEMNUMBER,
                DatabaseHandler.KEY_DESCRIPTION,
                DatabaseHandler.KEY_PICKINGSEQUENCE,
                DatabaseHandler.KEY_QTYONHAND,
                DatabaseHandler.KEY_QTYCOUNTED,
                DatabaseHandler.KEY_STOCKUNIT, DatabaseHandler.KEY_STATUS };
        int[] to = new int[] { R.id.text_itemnumber, R.id.text_desc,
                R.id.text_ps, R.id.text_qoh, R.id.text_qc, R.id.text_su,
                R.id.text_st };
        sca = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.list_row, cu, columns,
                to, 0);
        lv.setAdapter(sca);



    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.e("Failed", ex.getLocalizedMessage());
    }

}
```